# How to set CSS class to Button control using Session value in design page

Tags: asp.net, css

I want to set CSS class to `asp:Button` control using Session value. I have tried this, but it does not works.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Application,Save %>" CssClass="<%# Common.SessionInfo.Button %>" ValidationGroup="save"
                        OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```

It works fine, when I set it from code behind

```
btnSave.CssClass = Common.SessionInfo.Button;
```

Please help...

Comment: `<%= Common.SessionInfo.Button %>` Use **=** instead of **#**. The code block will work just like `Response.Write`.

Comment: what is `Common` in your code. You need to use it's namespace in `.aspx` file. like `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>`

Comment: Common is a public class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `DataBind` method from code behind as in code below. When you use expression like `<%# %>` then you need to call databind on that server control in your code-behind.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.btnSave.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create method in your code behind:

```
public string GetButtonClass(){
    return Session["your_key"].ToString();
}
```

and call this method to your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Application,Save %>" CssClass="<%=GetButtonClass()%>" ValidationGroup="save"
                    OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
```